Set cookies inside server action does not work in Nextjs
I'm trying to make a fetch wrapper to refresh access token. This method is called monkey patch.
Essentially, whenever the request returns 401 or 403 status, I will call an API to get new access token along with refresh token and set them in cookies, then call the request again with new tokens.
However, I'm stuck at the part where I need to store new tokens in cookies. It seems like cookie.set() doesn't work even though I have made the file a server action by using "use server". And in my login server action, cookies.set() works fine, but in this code, the cookies.set() doesn't work and it throws an error. Can somebody shed light on this?
"use server"

export async function customFetch(url: string, options: FetchOptions = {}) {
  const cookieStore = cookies();
  let accessToken = cookieStore.get("accessToken")?.value;

  const response = await fetch(url, {
    ...options,
    headers: {
      ...options.headers,
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    },
  });

  // if receive 401 or 403 status, we call the refresh token api
  if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
    console.log("we caught the error");
    // call the fetchRefreshToken. if there's an error, meaning the refresh token is invalid, we need user to login
    try {    
      let refreshToken = cookieStore.get("refreshToken")?.value;

      if (!refreshToken) {
        throw new Error("No refresh token found");
      }

      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/refresh-token", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ refresh_token: refreshToken }),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Fail to get refresh token");
      }
    
      const responseData = await response.json();
      console.log("the new tokens are ", responseData);

      console.log("message 1 works") // IT WORKS UNTIL THIS LINE
  
      cookieStore.set({
        name: "accessToken",
        value: responseData.tokens.access_token,
        httpOnly: true,
      }); // THIS DOESNT WORK

      console.log("message 2 works")

      cookieStore.set({
        name: "refreshToken",
        value: responseData.tokens.refresh_token,
        httpOnly: true,
      }); // THIS DOESNT WORK

      console.log("message 3 works")
      
      accessToken = cookieStore.get("accessToken")?.value;

      console.log("the second access token is", accessToken)

      // Retry the original request with the new access token
      const retryResponse = await fetch(url, {
        ...options,
        headers: {
          ...options.headers,
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      });

      return retryResponse;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Failed to refresh token, redirecting to login...");
      redirect("/login");
    }
  }

  return response;
}

